# Javascript variables affecting one another

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm creating a basic algorithm to find the longest word in a string. However I'm running into a problem where two arrays assigned different variables are showing as equal. Here is my code:

```js
function LongestWord(sen) {
  var arr = sen.split(' '); // arr = ['How', 'is', 'your', 'dinner']
  var wordsLength = arr.map(function(word) { // wordsLength = [3, 2, 4, 6]
    return word.length;
  });
  var sortLength = wordsLength.sort(function(a, b) { //sortLength = [6, 4, 3, 2]
    return b - a;
  });

  console.log(wordsLength === sortLength);

}
LongestWord("How is your dinner");
```

I commented what I expected each array to equal in the code. Yet somehow `wordsLength` is being sorted before the `sortLength` var is even declared. I know this because the console logs `"TRUE"`. I considered that map might somehow automatically sort the variable but when I comment out `sortLength`, `wordsLength` is unsorted as I originally expected.
Obviously the second variable declaration is affecting the first one but I am not sure why. I'm unaware of any concept that causes this behavior.

Comment: See documentation for **[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**. >>>The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. Meaning the current array being sorted is modified and returned.

Comment: The objects and the arrays in Javascript are passed by reference, so in your code wordsLength and sortLength are pointing to the same array, and for that they take value of the last modification.

Comment: What do you actually want to get as the result, the length of the longest word, or the longest word itself?

Answer (score 1):

array.sort() sorts the array in place **and** returns it.
So, you sorted arrLength and assigned it to sortLength, and now they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is a function that sorts the elements of an array in place, so you need a shallow copy of of the array before sort, use for this the function [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Your code is now plus a new function to get the longest word:

```js
function LongestWord(sen) {
  var arr = sen.split(' '); // arr = ['How', 'is', 'your', 'dinner']
  var wordsLength = arr.map(function(word) { // wordsLength = [3, 2, 4, 6]
    return word.length;
  });
  var sortLength = wordsLength.slice().sort(function(a, b) { //sortLength = [6, 4, 3, 2]
    return b - a;
  });

  document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + (wordsLength === sortLength) + '</p>';

}

function NewLongestWord(sen) {
  if (sen.trim().length == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  var arr = sen.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) { //sortLength = [6, 4, 3, 2]
    return b.length - a.length;
  });
  return arr[0];
}


document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + (NewLongestWord("How is your dinner")) + '</p>';

LongestWord("How is your dinner");
```

Comment: Sort function actually is sorting the arrLength var

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map), because the array can be sorted by length with an temporary array.

The better solution is not to sort the array. Instead of sorting use an iterator like [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because only one iteration is needed and not more like for the sorting.

```js
function longestWord(sen) {
    // the array to be sorted
    var list = sen.split(' '); // arr = ['How', 'is', 'your', 'dinner']
    
    // temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
    var mapped = list.map(function (el, i) {
        return { index: i, value: el.length };
    });

    // sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
    mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.value-a.value;
    });

    // container for the resulting order
    var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
        return list[el.index];
    });
    return result.shift();
}

function longestWord2(s) {
    return s.split(' ').reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
    });
}

document.write(longestWord('How is your dinner') + '<br>');
document.write(longestWord2('How is your dinner') + '<br>');
```